# ImportError outside python shell

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am unable to execute a script unless I run it in the python shell.

Twilio.py Script:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
auth_token  = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(body="Jenny please?! I love you <3",
    to="+xxxxxxxxxxx",    # Replace with your phone number
    from_="+xxxxxxxxxxx") # Replace with your Twilio number
print message.sid
```

Python is installed to c:\python27.

Below are my different attempts to execute the script and its output.

```
C:\Users\myname> c:\python27\python -u "D:\\twilio.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\\twilio.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
  File "D:\twilio.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
ImportError: No module named rest

C:\Users\myname> c:\python27\python.exe
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> execfile("D:/twilio.py")
<sid output removed>
>>>
```

As you can see above when I run the script inside the python shell I do not get any errors and I receive a text message on my phone. When I run the script via python.exe -u I receive an ImportError.

I checked the sys.path for both methods and here is the output:

```
>>> execfile("D:/BT Syncs/Main Sync/Programming/syspath.py")
['', 'C:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\twilio-4.4.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2015.4-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.9.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\httplib2-0.9.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\python27\\python27.zip', 'C:\\python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\python27', 'C:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages']
>>>

C:\Users\myname> c:\python27\python -u "D:\\syspath.py"
['D:\\', 'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\twilio-4.4.0-py2.7.egg', 'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2015.4-py2.7.egg', 'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.9.0-py2.7.egg', 'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\httplib2-0.9.1-py2.7.egg', 'c:\\python27\\python27.zip', 'c:\\python27\\DLLs', 'c:\\python27\\lib', 'c:\\python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'c:\\python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'c:\\python27', 'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Any ideas?

Comment: rename your twilio.py file to something else and retry.  The import statement might be getting confused between your py file and twilio module.  worth a shot

Comment: Renaming the file worked. Good catch!

Comment: Good deal.  Yeah, those can be tricky

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tkinter error: cannot import name 'Frame'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146739/tkinter-error-cannot-import-name-frame)